# Display Posts with template on a Page

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts

OK, I'm sure some WP pros here will think this is a dumb question, and I'll probably get some flak, but I have actually read plenty of documentation, and I just don't think I'm even going in the right direction, anymore.

I am somewhat experienced with PHP, but i have little experience with wordpress.

My client bought a WP theme-- and the theme has a built-in template for *posts* -

However, when I used the suggested method `query_posts()` - the template was stripped from the post content when displayed on the page.

SO, what methods do I use to include the other parts of the template? 
I've checked a few files like posts.php and post_template.php -- but it seems like I'm not even going in the right direction.

So whatever help anyone can offer would be fantastic-- 
I think if I got going in the right direction, I could figure out the trickier details, like how to include aspects of the template only once, even though I want to display 5 posts at a time on this page-- But if you know something different has to be done for that, then I REALLY appreciate the help.

Comment: what theme? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As written, this isn't an answerable question. We don't know what code you're using, what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and what isn't working as expected/intended. Please **edit your question** to include actual template code, along with a more explicit statement regarding *what you're trying to accomplish*.

Comment: @Micheal -- 
Well, I would post the site, but its a shitty site, although it is exactly what the client asked for.

They have a Page -- that they want to be their "blog" page -- and they have a template-- Destro.Pro -- that they want to use for their Posts -- And they want 5 posts at a time-- which, isn't too hard to achieve with query_posts() -- but they want the theme they paid for to be included in the post's format. 

Like I said, I am inexperienced with WP and I am not sure how to do that. 
I really wish they had let me do the site from the ground up. 
Does that answer your question? =/

Comment: @ChipBennett -- 
AH, crap, ok. I will edit my question to your spec. 
I truly apologize-- I don't mean to be *that idiot* --
I will rephrase this, tomorrow, and I hope you revisit this and give me the valuable input that you want to give, but I was not competent enough to allow you to input. 

I deeply apologize, and I sincerely thank you for giving me criteria to sharpen my question. Duly noted, and I will keep that in mind for all of my future stackexchange questions. 

Sincere thanks to both of you --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`query_posts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/query_posts/) is a horrible function and shouldn't be used. Also it doesn't has much to do with loading template, since it was originally designed to be used *in* template. Should not be used.

If you are looking for logic of how WP picks template files from theme to load see [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

If you just want to load some [part of] template manually, [`get_template_part()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_template_part/) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Wonderful! This is likely the new direction I was hoping someone would guide me towards -- 

I am going to let this question ferment a few days-- and once I investigate this more, I will have more concise feedback to give-- And I hope you will add more input in a day or two.